# Formatting decimal digits for double inside label text

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have this line of code:

```
label4.Text = "(" + x1 + ", 0), (" + x2 + ",0)";
```

Both *x1* and *x2* are double values. I cannot make them display with two decimal digits. I know that I can use `{0:N2}` but I cannot find right syntax way to use it because I have two values in string I want to display. How should I write it to make both values (*x1* and *x2*) display in string with just 2 decimal digits?

Comment: The compiler will call `ToString()` for variables , but you can convert to string yourself, e.g. `x1.ToString("0.00")` (or `"N2"`). Though this way of concatenating strings it bad. Use *interpolated strings* (@Rene's answer) for readability, less error prone, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this my friend:

```
double x1 = 10.5;
double x2 = 5.666;

label4.Text = String.Format("({0:N2}), ({1:N2})", x1, x2);
```

Result for this expression:

```
 "(10.50), (5.67)"
```

Answer (score 4):

By using [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Starting), you can create tags in your format string, then supply a matching number of parameters to populate the tags:

```
string.Format("({0:0.00}, 0), ({1:0.00},0)", x1, x2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
label4.Text = string.Format("({0:0.00}, 0), ({1:0.00},0)", x1, x2);
```

or using [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) in C# 6

```
label4.Text = $"({x1:0.00}, 0), ({x2:0.00},0)";
```